# Real Curve for Complex Function

Tags: functional-equations, real-numbers, curves

I was tasked with solving the functional equation
$$f(x)+f(2x)=2x$$
and I found that one possible function $f$ could be
$$f(x)=\frac{2x+(-1)^{\log_2 x}}{3}$$
This function is real whenever $x=2^k$, $k \in \mathbb Z$, and it is mostly complex otherwise. I was wondering if, in the real plane, there is a function $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ that connects the points of $f(x)$ that lie in the real plane with a smooth curve. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Is it even possible? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: How about just $f(x)=\frac23 x$ as a solution to the original equation?

Comment: I know that is also a solution to the functional equation - that isn't what the question is about though. What I want to know is whether or not there is a way to connect the points in the reals of my function with a smooth curve also in the reals. The functional equation is just how I came to be considering this problem, but it isn't part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no smooth function defined on all of $\mathbb R$ such that
$$ f(2^k) = \frac{2\cdot 2^k + (-1)^k}3 $$
for all $k\in\mathbb Z$.

By considering large negative $k$ we can see that there are $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$ where $f(x)$ must be either close to $\frac13$ or close to $-\frac13$ -- so your given values won't even extend to a *continuous* function defined at $0$.

---

If you restrict your attention to the positive reals, you could do, for example:
$$ f(x) = \frac23x + \frac13\cos\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{\ln 2} \ln x\Bigr) $$
which extends to any complex domain you can extend the natural logarithm to (*and* solves your original functional equation too).

Comment: Thank you so much! That last function helps a lot.

Comment: @Frpzzd: I found it by considering that $(-1)^k$ can mean either $e^{k\pi i}$ or $e^{-k \pi i}$ and then averaging them to get something that's always real.